# Current User UID different than Auth UID?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Warning: Im very new to coding in general and xcode

Running Xcode 8.2

Anyways, So I have saved my users authentication details, email password. And I save them under user/currentUser.UID and it gives username and email. I want to retrieve the username and put it as a label text but the UID's are different?!

Grab username through database and set a label to the username

```
@IBOutlet weak var welcomeHomeUsername: UILabel!

func welcomeHomeAddUsername() {


    guard let uid12 = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    print("User ID post guard: \(uid12)")

    ref.child("users").child(uid12).child("username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshotWelcome in

        print(snapshotWelcome)
        let welcomeHomeUser = snapshotWelcome.value as? String
        self.welcomeHomeUsername.text = welcomeHomeUser

    })

}
```

Then this is the code to allow users to sign up with firebase auth and then saves the username and email values in /users/(uid)/

```
@IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: Any)
{


    //Authenticate User//
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

        if user != nil {
            print("User Created")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backLogin", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            print("error no seg")
        }
    }
    //Successfully Authenticated User//




    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }



    //Add User to Database//
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "~~~My Database URL~~~")
    let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
    let values = ["username": usernameTextField.text, "email": emailTextField.text]
    usersReference.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in

        if err != nil {
            print("error no user created")
        }

        if (Auth.auth().currentUser != nil){
            print("user id: " + (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!);
            return
        }
        print("Saved user succesfully into Firebase DB")


    }


}
```

Then in my console output

```
    user id: mrsIBAAl2LVb7FetVxnMwBtMJ562

    User ID post guard: 0QkYbdPdH7QdZsdRjck53l4Ekrk2
    Snap (message1) Welcome to the Beta!
    Snap (username) <null>
```

I also have a function that gets the MOTD which right now is "welcome to the test!" and that is a branch in my database which I reference in a different function but I don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: Can you show how are you creating the user with the auth of firebase, because it seems like you are creating 2 accounts on the same client.

Comment: @GiovannyPiñeros I added the code for the sign up IBAction to the post.

Comment: Make sure that you log out your user. Also, are you doing all of these on the same view controller?. Sorry for the late response, What is your app flow eg => ViewControllerSignUp => ViewControllerWelcome... etc

Comment: Would I be able to log out the user after authenticating them and then still access their username and information at the homescreen? So my app flow is ViewController => LoginViewController => SignUpViewController => LoginViewController => HomeViewController. I think thats what you mean by app flow, the way the user would go through the viewcontrollers? The user swipes up on a view controller to get to the login controller. I took a screenshow of part of my storyboard https://imgur.com/a/Wdjsp2Z

Comment: Yes you will be able to log back in. I think that may be you are creating several users when you use the app. Its difficult for me to say you an exact error, but review your logic. If it helps you can go here https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios there are several examples, one of those examples show you how to work with auth. Beaware that you have to read and understad the code in the examples. But it is the best way to learn,

Comment: @GiovannyPiñeros thank you, I’ll take a look and take some time to read through it.

Comment: So, I finally found a previous thread on here that is my problem, I just do not understand how it was solved and I cant post a comment on it since I am new to this site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833358/different-uid-in-firebase-database-and-in-firebase-auth

If maybe I could get an explanation on how this thread was solved, I will mark this thread as a duplicate of the above post or remove it entirely.

Comment: Hello Shawn, as i told you. Review your logic. At the end of the answer of the thread that you've posted, the user said this "you variable called uid is from an old account.", That means that the person was creating and account and using and old account uid, which means that the logic of the program wasn't clear.

Comment: For you to write a good program, sort of speak, you have to have a clear flow of the logic of the thing that you are creating. Take a look comment of the question author in the answer " I did not spot the misplacement of some block of code", all of that bears down to how the programmer set the logic of the program. I have been in your shoes, so my advice to you is before you write code first draw in a flowchart   what you want to achive, an make it as especific as posible. Ideally you should write it blocks of code that work simillary as lego blocks, so you can re use this blocks for your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EUREKA!
I found the problem!

I looked through the flow of my sign up and was testing different parts of it when I noticed that the UID in the database was the past UID that was the auth, so when a new auth UID was made the old one showed up in the database. I looked through the flow using console prints and found that the authentication and creation of the user was happening AFTER the database was logging the user! So to fix this, I put my authentication in its own function, then at the end of that once the user was authenticated, I called the function that adds the user to the databases and this works!

```
@IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: Any)
{

    signupTrue = 0
    print(signupTrue)

    let ref3 = Database.database().reference()

    ref3.child("schools").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.hasChild(self.schoolNameTextfield.text!){
            print("true school exist")
            signupTrue = 1
            print(signupTrue)

            self.authUserFunc()

        }
        else {
            print("false school doesn't exist")
            signupTrue = 2
            print(signupTrue)
        }
    })
    print("Test ending ref3")
}



func authUserFunc() {

    //Authenticate User//
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

        if user != nil {
            print("User Created")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backLogin", sender: self)
            self.addToDatabase()
        }
        else {
            print("error no seg")
        }
    }
    //Successfully Authenticated User//

}




func addToDatabase() {
    print("Starting add to database")
        print("starting signup")


        //Add User to School Database//
        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "~~~My Database URL~~~")
        let userSchoolReference = ref.child("schools").child(schoolNameTextfield.text!).child("users").child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
        let values = ["username": usernameTextField.text!, "email": emailTextField.text!]
        userSchoolReference.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in


            if err != nil {
                print("error no school user created")
            }

            if (Auth.auth().currentUser != nil){
                print("Saved user succesfully into School Firebase DB")
                //print("user id: " + (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!);
                return
            }
        }



        //add user to users file//
        //let userReference = ref.child("users").child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
        let values2 = ["username": usernameTextField.text!, "email": emailTextField.text!, "password": passwordTextField.text!]


    Database.database().reference().child("users").child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)").updateChildValues(values2) { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil{
            print("Error no user created")
            return
        }
    }

    print("\(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)")

//end func addToDatabase
}
```

Thank you for all your help! I think now that I am over this bump, ill be able to move forward with my coding with more knowledge!